# Join without foreign key for condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get two tables like this:

```
create table #table1 (data1 int)
create table #table2 (data2 int)

insert into #table1 (data1) values (1),(2),(3)
insert into #table2 (data2) values (4),(5),(6)
```

I want to make a query, that returns two columns like this:

```
data1   data2

    1       4
    2       5
    3       6
```

I found one solution for this:

```
select t1.data1, t2.data2 from 
 (select row_number() over (order by data1) as [Index], data1 from #table1) as t1 inner join 
 (select row_number() over (order by data2) as [Index], data2 from #table2) as t2 on (t1.[Index] = t2.[Index])
```

Do you know other ways to join tables (any joins except cross) without keys?

**EDIT:** I look for solution without `cursor` and `temporary tables`.

Comment: What do you mean *without keys* ? IMO, you have the correct query for the desired output

Comment: To me it seems there IS some hidden thing that is actually linking the rows, otherwise the query would make no sense. Which is the actualy business use for this kind of query? What if your table2 had 4 rows?

Comment: @Thomas, I would like to find another solution without using `over` clause (in case of using MySQL for example)

Comment: @Janne, I need to fill third table with pregenerated data from this two tables.

Comment: If you want to know how it's done for MySQL, then ask for it explicitly. There's no other way than row_number(), and don't work with cursors if you still want to have reasonable performance.

Comment: Just create 2 temp tables which will both have identity, then insert your datas to those temp tables and then do inner join on the ID's on the insert into if your both tables have equal number of rows and the order is what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
create table table1 (data1 int)
create table table2 (data2 int)
insert into table1 (data1) values (1),(2),(3)
insert into table2 (data2) values (4),(5),(6)

create table #table1 
(id int identity(1,1),
data1 int)

create table #table2 
(id int identity(1,1),
data2 int)

insert into #table1 (data1) select data1 from table1
insert into #table2 (data2) select data2 from table2

create table table3
(data1 int,
data2 int)

insert into table3 (data1, data2) 
select #table1.data1, #table2.data2 
from #table1
inner join #table2 on #table1.id = #table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

what will be output in this case if i insert below values 
insert into #table1 (data1) values (1),(2),(3)
insert into #table2 (data2) values (2),(3),(4)
may you need

```
select t1.data1, t2.data2 from t1,t2
```

Comment: data1   data2

    1       4
    2       5
    3       6

Comment: try select t1.data1, t2.data2 from t1,t2

Comment: this returns same as cross join

Comment: why you want to avoid this ? any other data issue there ?

Comment: In my real project first table has about 1000 records and 10 fields, and about 1000 records from second table. Also i use this query in `insert ... select` statement.